# Dying SanDisk Memory Stick Pro Duo

Tags: memory-card, filesystem-corruption

I have a Memory Stick Pro Duo and after attempting to delete the largest file from a Mac the stick has become unusable. I can almost access it. When I put it in my PC I can open/delete/copy/paste/rename/modify one file/folder, then it can't detect the card. If I reinsert the card I can move on to the next file, but this is really annoying and my PSP won't read it at all. The memory card access light will flash for a really long time before it says that every file is corrupted. When I have tried to format it with either the PC, PSP, or a camera that uses a memory stick pro duo, it fails. I've tried with all the different options on windows, I tried formatting it through CMD, but nothing I have tried works. Should I copy every file off one by one or is there a way to fix it?

If there is no way to fix it, can anyone tell me if the Mac was possibly the cause? The problem started after I used a tool on Mac OSX Lion to find the largest file and then tried to use the tool to delete it. The file I tried to delete is still there so it makes me wonder if it was the tool was the cause of the corruption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of formatting, try removing the partition and then adding a new one, then format the drive.  [Gnome Partition Editor](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/) is a great tool for this.  It can do just about anything partition and filesystem related.

If it still cant be done, the stick is probably defective.  Flash media does wear out over time.

Comment: Asker said he already tried formatting it and it fails.

Comment: thats why I said to remove the partition first

Comment: I will try the partition editor, and I don't think it's worn out. It's fairly new and I have a separate Memory Stick Pro Duo from Sony that is years older than this one. How do you use the Gparted tool? I can't figure out how to do it. It wants to be burned to a CD or copied to a flash drive.